# Find a basis for each $V\cap W$ and $V+W$

Tags: linear-algebra

This is the first time trying dimensions of $V+W$ and $V\cap W$, so I wanted to check if I did this correctly.

> Let $V$ be the vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ generated by the vectors $$v_1=(1,2,-1,-2), v_2=(3,1,1,1), v_3=(-1,0,1,-1),$$
>   and $W$ the subspace generated by $$w_1=(2,5,-6,-5), w_2=(-1,2,-7,3).$$
>   Find the dimension and a basis for each of $V\cap W$ and $V+W$.

Comment: "So I wanted to check if I did this correctly".. You didn't put your working in your post.

Comment: For the sum you can see which vectors are linear independent between both sets and the answer will be the set of independents.

Comment: You should write down what you did to *really check* ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write down a matrix with all the given vectors as rows, and reduce it as usual:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&2&-1&-2\\3&1&1&1\\-1&0&1&-1\\2&5&-6&-5\\-1&2&-7&3\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1&2&-1&-2\\0&-5&4&7\\0&2&0&-3\\0&1&-4&-1\\0&4&-8&1\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1&2&-1&-2\\0&-5&4&7\\0&0&8/5&-1/5\\0&0&-16/5&2/5\\0&0&-24/5&33/5\end{pmatrix}$$

We clearly have that in the last matrix, the fourth row is a multiple of the third one, and all the rest four rows are linear independent, thus

$$V\cap W=\text{Span}\,\left\{\;(2,5,-6,-5)\;\right\}$$

This must be enough to answer your whole question.